# Impossible could have

Tags: grammar

I killed a monster using my gun yesterday.

Say it was impossible for any other weapon to kill the monster. The gun was the only solution capable of killing it.

"No other weapon could have killed it"
Is this the correct tense for describing such a situation?

Comment: You got it. But be aware that your opening sentence is an established trap that begs the question what was the monster doing with your gun? Groucho: I shot an **elephant in my PJs**! What was he doing in your PJs?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Technically speaking, yes, this is a possible interpretation. But I wonder if there are *any* native speakers who would actually be confused by this formal ambiguity.

Comment: *The gun was the only solution capable of killing it.* ... I don't think solutions kill things - guns do. *The gun was the only **thing** capable of killing it.*

Comment: What @Greybeard said. The gun itself isn't a solution - the actual solution is ***use of the gun*** or ***using the gun*** - either of those noun phrases can be used as the syntactic "subject" in ***Only [X] is capable of killing the monster***.

Comment: @linguisticturn Of course not, which is why the Groucho joke is funny. You don't notice the ambiguity until he asks the question.